# Error in hw(train): The time series should have frequency greater than 1 (forecast library)

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

What does this mean? My timeSeries has a frequency of 365, doesn't it? What I'm trying to do is make 3 years of daily forecasts, one day at a time. To put it differently, I'd like to get a forecast for the next day, 365*3 times.

```
library(forecast)
df = read.csv("./files/all_var_df.csv")

ts = as.timeSeries(df[, c(1, 2)])
train = as.timeSeries(ts[0:3285, ])
validation = ts[3285:4380]

fit_hw <- hw(train)
fit2_hw <- hw(validation, model=fit_hw)
onestep_hw <- fitted(fit2_hw)
```

> Error in hw(train): The time series should
>   have frequency greater than 1.

**Here is some info that might help you answer:**

```
class(train)
> [1] "timeSeries"

head(train, 3)
> 2005-01-01 101634.4 
> 2005-01-02 106812.5 
> 2005-01-03 119502.8 

length(train)
> [1] 3285
```

Comment: Please provide sample data you used in df dataframe

Comment: @RiteshPorwal Thanks for your answer, I could certainly do that, how do you suggest I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually seeing your data I can only speculate. I can, however, recreate this problem using available datasets in R. In the `library(fpp2)` in R, the dataset `ausair` contains "Total annual air passengers (in millions) including domestic and international aircraft passengers of air carriers registered in Australia. 1970-2016."

Reading in this dataset as a ts (`air <- window(ausair, start = 1990)`), we get the following:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1990 
End = 2016 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 17.55340 21.86010 23.88660 26.92930 26.88850 28.83140 30.07510 30.95350
 [9] 30.18570 31.57970 32.57757 33.47740 39.02158 41.38643 41.59655 44.65732
[17] 46.95177 48.72884 51.48843 50.02697 60.64091 63.36031 66.35527 68.19795
[25] 68.12324 69.77935 72.59770
```

I will now use the `hw()` function to train with:

```
fc <- hw(air, seasonal = "additive")
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error in hw(air, seasonal = "additive") : 
  The time series should have frequency greater than 1.
```

What has happened here is that each datapoint corresponds to a whole year. So the Holt-Winters method is unable to find seasonality. The seasonal portion of the HW method follows the following equation:

[image]

Where the term [image] represents the seasonality, and *m* the frequency. It doesn't make sense to talk about a repetitive seasonal pattern if there is only 1 data point in a time period.

The fix to your problem is in the way you define your time series object with `ts()`. One argument of the time series function is frequency. Without seeing your data I can't say what that value should be set to. [Here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/) is a site explaining the term frequency. It will be dependent on what seasonality your data exhibits. Does it repeat a seasonal pattern every week? Every quarter? If there is no seasonal pattern, you can switch to the function `holt()` which only uses an exponential decay term and trend term to find a pattern and will not give your error.

Comment: could @DeathByGreen replace [ts (`air <- window(ausair, start = 1990)`)] by [`ts (air <- window(ausair, start = 1990))`? Such a little edition is not allowed.